# How do I avoid liquibase running multiple times during JUNIT Test cases

Tags: spring, junit, liquibase, junit5

I have an application and I'm managing database with Liquibase. While I was looking at my package process during build jobs, I noticed that the Liquibase is being run multiple times. I'm trying to optimize my application code so that the build gets done faster. I've already implemented parallel test case running and I got my time reduced from 18 mins to 10 mins which is good. I would still like to optimize it to be faster. I noticed that my Liquibase is running multiple times to set up a H2 database. How can I optimize this process of test cases so that Liquibase is run only once and I have test cases running on it.

Comment: how many `@SpringBootTest` annotations do you have in your tests?

Comment: Hi @bilak, I have multiple instances of "@SpringBootTest". I get what you are pointing out. I'm kind of in the thought process on how better can i optimize this? Can you help with any advice?

Comment: maybe just add one `AbstractIT` where you will have a common things and then extend it with each individual integration test. Don't share same identifiers that could cause an  issue between tests or do a `repository.deleteAll` in `@BeforeEach` to cleanup the database before each test.